# The use of prepositions "in" and "within" - "I will graduate in/within the next year"

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I am curious if these sentences make any sense to you:

1. I will graduate next year
2. I will graduate in the next year
3. I will graduate within the next year

If those sentences do make sense, could you please elaborate more on the differences between the three?

Answer (score -1):

*Next year* = the next calendar year = in 2020. Or possibly, since your sentence is about graduation, at the end of the next academic year.

*In/within the next year* = at some time in the next twelve months from now.